# Display part in Android

Tags: android

I am retrieving data from my database.  In my database one field price with value.  I retrieved data, I am displaying all data in a `ListView` (with a `TextView` inside it).  I want display format as `Price:67787`.  But it displaying only 67787.  I searched,  but I can't find the correct answer.

Comment: You should post your code as it's impossible to say what goes wrong.

Comment: You will get the value of price from database so set it into textview as:textview.setText("Price:"+value); or In xml file where you have declared textview,set its text as android:text="Price:",and set value in your class

Comment: Thanks AkashG...I am using cursor adapter like this.Then how can i set the value:     String[] from = new String[] { db.KEY_INCOME};      int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1 }; SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
             new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.columnview, c, from, to);
//     System.out.println("notes="+notes.getCount());
//     setListAdapter(notes);    
     lv.setAdapter(notes);           how can i set??

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] from = new String[] { db.KEY_INCOME};

Add Followin v v v v v v v v v v v

for(int i=0; i<from.length; i++) {

    from[i] = "Price:"+from[i];

}

^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^

int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1 };

SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.columnview, c, from, to);

//System.out.println("notes="+notes.getCount());

// setListAdapter(notes); lv.setAdapter(notes);
```

/*
I think you are filling value of TextView(inside List-view).
At there, you may have set

```
yourTextView.setText(PRICE_FROM_DATABASE);
```

Instead that set as following:

```
yourTextView.setText("Price:"+PRICE_FROM_DATABASE);
```

*/

Comment: Thanks Chintan Raghwani..I am using cursor adapter like this.Then how can i set the value:     String[] from = new String[] { db.KEY_INCOME};      int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1 }; SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
             new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.columnview, c, from, to);
//     System.out.println("notes="+notes.getCount());
//     setListAdapter(notes);    
     lv.setAdapter(notes);           how can i set??

Comment: It shows some error..java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'price:price' does not exist

Comment: This is error related to DataBase Reading, You are reading "price:price" column from DataBase; instead you have to read onle "price" from DataBase. YOU have not implemented my code properly. JUST CHECK MY CODE AND COMPARE IT WITH YOURS.

Comment: This is my code after your update:       String[] from = new String[] { db.KEY_INCOME};              for(int i=0; i<from.length; i++) {

          from[i] = "price:"+from[i];      int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1};

    }                                      SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
             new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.columnview, c, from, to);